# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be a root of
$$ f(x)=x^{19}-7x^{16}+77x^{11}+63x^5-35x^3+14=0$$
Is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$? Justify your answer.

**Solution:** Using Eisenstein's Criterion, with $p=7$, we show $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

To show $\alpha^8$ is a root of $f(x)$, do I try to find $\alpha$ explicit?

Is there a trick to show $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\implies\alpha^8\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\implies\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, but now you need to show the other direction.

Comment: How would I do the other direction?

Comment: Hint: $19=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8)][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8):\mathbb{Q}]$

Comment: Can I say that $|\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^8):\mathbb{Q}|=8k$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$?

Comment: But if so, I can say that $8k \not | 19$. Hence we don't have that direction

Comment: It is not enough to show that $\alpha^8$ is not a root of $f(x)$. $\sqrt{2}+1$ is not a root of $x^2-2$, but it is certainly the case that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+1)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to show that $x$ and $x^8$ generate the same extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, apriori, $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(x^8) \subset \mathbb{Q}(x)$. What you also know is that the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(x)/\mathbb{Q}$ is $19$. Also, you know the formula for the degrees of the intermediate extension
$$[\mathbb{Q}(x)\colon \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(x)\colon \mathbb{Q}(x^8)]\cdot [\mathbb{Q}(x^8)\colon \mathbb{Q}]$$
Since the LHS is $19$, a prime, $[\mathbb{Q}(x^8)\colon \mathbb{Q}]$ can only be $1$ or $19$. It cannot be $1$, since $x^8\not\in \mathbb{Q}$. So it must be $19$, and therefore $\mathbb{Q}(x^8) = \mathbb{Q}(x)$.

Now, to provide an explicit equation for $x^8\colon = y$, we can use Groebner bases, see the WA [calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7Bx%5E19-7x%5E%2816%29%2B77x%5E%2811%29%2B63x%5E5-35x%5E3%2B14%2C%20y%20-%20x%5E8%7D%2C%7By%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%5D). Moreover, we can find an explicit expression of $x$ in terms of $y$. It is quite involved, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7Bx%5E19-7x%5E%2816%29%2B77x%5E%2811%29%2B63x%5E5-35x%5E3%2B14%2C%20y%20-%20x%5E8%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D%5D).